# Trying to evaluate the constant term

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

Suppose you are given that

$$\biggr (\sqrt[3]x - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt x} \biggr )^{15}$$

I'm trying to evaluate the constant term.

$$\sum^{15}_{n = 0} \binom{6}{r}x^{5-r}\cdot -\dfrac{\sqrt x}{x}$$

How can I take it from there?

Comment: I don't understand what you're given. You just said "Suppose you are given <expression>", did you mean some equality?

Comment: I don' t think the constant term will have an $x$ in it...

Comment: The summands don’t depend on $n$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$\sum^{15}_{n = 0} \binom{6}{r}x^{5-r}\cdot -\dfrac{\sqrt x}{x}$$

Why $6$? This looks a bit strange; from the binomial theorem:

$$\biggr (\sqrt[3]x - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt x} \biggr )^{15} = \sum^{15}_{n = 0} \binom{15}{n}\left(\sqrt[3]x\right)^n\left(\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt x}\right)^{15-n}\tag{$*$}$$

Rewrite:

$$\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt[3]x\right)^n\left(\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt x}\right)^{15-n}&
=\left(-1\right)^{15-n}\left(x^\tfrac{1}{3}\right)^n\left(x^{-\tfrac{1}{2}}\right)^{15-n} \\[8pt]
& =\left(-1\right)^{15-n}\;x^{\tfrac{n}{3}}x^{-\tfrac{1}{2}(15-n)} \\[8pt]
& =\left(-1\right)^{15-n}\;x^{\color{blue}{\tfrac{n}{3}-\tfrac{1}{2}(15-n)}}
\end{align}$$

You have the constant term if the exponent of $x$ is equal to $0$, so when:
$${\color{blue}{\tfrac{n}{3}-\tfrac{1}{2}(15-n)}}=0 \iff n = \ldots$$
Plug this value for $n$ back in $(*)$ but it is clear the coefficient is simply $\left(-1\right)^{15-n}\binom{15}{n}$.

Comment: Why is it $x^{-\dfrac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: Properties of exponents: $\sqrt{x}=x^{1/2}$ so $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=x^{-1/2}$. I did forget the minus of the term $\color{red}{-}\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, let me add that.